# Laravel passport bug to multi-auth and multi model ( database )

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I want to create Multi auth that have two parts (user And Restaurant admin). For this I create two Guard:

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'restapi' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'restaurants',
    ],
],
```

After Authentication, i created Token ( pesonal token ) with passport .

now with this token, i can see User data ( For Example user id 1 ) with url :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'UsersController@userInformation');
```

but this token worked on the Other guard !!!

```
Route::middleware('auth:restapi')->get('/restaurant', 'api\RestaurantApi@restaurantInformation');
```

Creation method User Token :

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$token = $user->createToken('token')->accessToken;
return $token;
```

Creation method Restaurant Admin Token :

```
$restaurant = App\Restaurant::find(1);
$token = $restaurant->createToken('token')->accessToken;
return $token;
```

two token work to every guard!

Comment: Write this on the official repository, not here.

Comment: yes , passport official repository writed :
https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/585